# Increasing Woocommerce attribute value length

Tags: php, woocommerce

I m trying to set up gobal attributes in Woocommerce and it will not let me save attribute values(not the names, but the actual values) that are longer than 200 characters. How can I increase this to unlimited?

I tried to find info in woocommerce/includes/wc-attribute-functions.php but can only find a max character number for the attribute name8which seems to be 28).

Comment: The limitation comes from WordPress database table `wp_terms` where `name` and `slug` columns are type `varchar(200)`, so there is nothing that you can do. Also more larger is the length of term names (and slugs), more slower the performances will be.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec What would you recommend in my situation: I have certain products that need warning notices displayed on the single product page( two kinds of warning notices). My thought was to set the two warning notices up as attributes but since they have too many characters, this does not work. Also, my attribute NAMES are short, but the values are long!

Comment: You can add for example a product custom field like an additional setting on admin product pages (type select or radio buttons). Then with a hooked function you can call that product custom field value to display in single product pages a notice depending on the custom field value…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks, I came up with another idea, maybe you can check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63830115/display-different-text-based-on-attribute-value-woocommerce

Comment: I have answered your new question.