# Display different text based on attribute value in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I have a global product attribute 'warning'. It has two values. Now I need to display different text  based on if the product has attribute value 1 or value 2 (and if it does not have that attribute at all, nothing should be displayed. I can display text with this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_warning', 35 );
function product_warning(){
    global $product;
    $taxonomy = 'pa_warning';
    $value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );
    if ( $value ) {
        $label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
        echo '<p>My Text</p>';
    }
}
```

but how can I display Text 1 if attribute value 1 is true, and text 2 if attribute value 2 is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead you will use 2 terms (values) for `pa_warning` like `1` and `2`, setting the correct term value for each related product. Then your code will be:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'product_warning', 35 );
function product_warning(){
    global $product;

    $taxonomy = 'pa_warning';

    $label_name = wc_attribute_label( $taxonomy );
    $term_value = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy );

    if ( $term_value == 1 ) {
        echo '<p>' ; __("My text message 1", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
    } elseif ( $term_value == 2 ) {
        echo '<p>' ; __("My text message 2", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Answer (score -1):

An array or something similar seems to be easiest(and probably quickest) way to do that. I believe that PHP still casts a null key value in an array to an empty string so declaring that shouldn't be necessary.

```
$warning = array(
 1 => "Warning number 1",
 2 => "Warning number 2",
);
echo $warning($term_value);
```